# How to migrate default export to named export?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Consider this code:

```
const MyComponent = props => <div>Hello</div>
export default React.memo(MyComponent)
```

This exports `React.memo(MyComponent)` as default. How can I instead turn this into a named export?

Comment: What name do you want to use? And why do you want to change it, does your module export multiple things?

Answer (score 2):

`export const` is what you're looking for:

```
const MyOriginalCOmponent = () => <div />
export const MyComponent = React.Memo(MyOriginalComponent)
```

Comment: Thank you! I upvoted the other answer, but only because content is the same and was a little bit earlier :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
const _MyComponent = props => <div>Hello</div>
export const MyComponent = React.memo(_MyComponent)
```

That would allow you to keep `MyComponent` as the name.  You could alternately keep your original name and export `MemoizedMyComponent` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply and it worked fine :-)